# Differences between "coordinate" (n.) and "co-ordinate" (n.)

Tags: hyphenation

I can't seem to spot any differences or usages where one would use the hyphenation version versus the non.

According to [Online Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=coordinate) they both point to coordinate.

I can see co-ordinate (v.) being used like co-pilot or co-chief, meaning a daulity or partner version. Example: Would you please co-ordinate with Bob. Meaning Bob is already ordinating and if you would also ordinate with him.

Yet I don't see that transferring over to the noun version meaning a location, especially in reference to mathematics and geography.

Is it simply a mix-up, or perhaps a localization issue (UK uses -, USA doesn't) or am I completely off base here?

Comment: I think your premise that people envisage "coordinate" as being based on "ordinate" (except in the mathematical sense) is probably not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a quick search in my NOAD, it seems they are the same exact term.

But, like I was thinking, **coordinate** is the term used, since if you search for *co-ordinate*, it will redirect you to the other one.

Look what happens if you search for *co-ordinate* [in the OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/spellcheck/?q=co-ordinate).

If you type them in Google, you'll get the following results:

- **Co-ordinate**: About 5,190,000 results;
- **Coordinate**: About 58,100,000 results.

Quite a difference... In the end I suppose the hyphened version is a variant, you might use either, although nowadays they're not really considered compound words anymore (another similar words is *cooperate*) but single words.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I concluded also - never thought of comparing Google result totals.

Comment: By the way, just for the record, my OED gives only the hyphened version. This proves that the other variant exists, but it still remains less used considering what I found. I thought it could interest you to know this point of view as well.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it simply a mix-up, or perhaps a localization issue (UK uses -, USA
>   doesn't) or am I completely off base here?

Yes, it is a local issue. I know from my experiences, that co-ordinate is the more common spelling in the UK. It's commonly used and is the spelling that I was taught, in the UK.

Whenever I have seen the word used in American writing, in publications or on the internet, I have noticed that it has always been with the coordinate spelling.

These dictionary pages mention that co-ordinate is the spelling in the UK.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/coordinate_1?q=co-ordinate#coordinate_1__3

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/coordinate_1

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/coordinate_2

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/coordinate_3

Comment: FWIW, the customer representative in a project in which I used to work, an Englishman, routinely asked for converting *coordinates* (geographical meaning) into *co-ordinates*. Now I understand why.

Comment: It makes sense, considering that the English spelling represents its English (rather than American) pronunciation. Co (rhymes with low) and then ordinate.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Longman DOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/coordinate_2), *co-ordinate* is British English.

And for better understanding of hyphen usage see [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hyphen):

> **Usage**
>   In modern English the use of hyphens is in general decreasing, especially in compound nouns: **website** is preferred to **web-site**, and **air raid** to **air-raid**. Hyphens are still often employed where a compound expression precedes a noun, as in *first-rate musician* or *twenty-odd people* (*twenty odd people* means something quite different!), but even in this context there is a growing trend to omit them. When a phrasal verb such as *build up* is made into a noun it is usually hyphenated (*a build-up of pressure* ). Note, however, that a normal phrasal verb should not be hyphenated: write *food to take away* not *food to take-away*, and *continue to build up your pension* not *continue to build-up your pension*

Answer (score 2):

They are the exact same term, as Alenanno says.  The reason for hyphenation is likely due to the fact that 'oo' has a different pronunciation than desired. In my experience with American English it's a preferred spelling when the word used is not likely to be familiar or when the pronunciation would otherwise be easily misread.

'Cooperate' is sometimes seen as 'co-operate' just to highlight that the double 'o' is two different vowel sounds.  'Cooperate' could be pronounced like 'coop' (as in a chicken coop).  Words like 'co-opt' are still always spelled with a hyphen precisely because of this.

'Cooperate', 'coordinate' and other words are common enough that the word is accepted sans-hypen.  People now recognize these words so the hyphen has stopped being necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are three acceptable spellings of coordinate: the official one is *coördinate* (with the trema indicating the start of a new syllable), and the resulting tremaless *coordinate* is thus also correct (but leads to the potential of an uninformed reader to pronounce it "COOR-dinate" with *coor* rhyming with *poor*). The hyphenated version *co-ordinate* is also correct, as it re-introduces the separation of two syllables between the two "o"s, but as was pointed out, this is not a compound word (so, strictly, the use of a hyphen is incorrect here – it is acceptable only because it is replacing a trema).

Usage of the various spellings seems to be in the ratio of about 5000:500:1 for *coordinate* : *co-ordinate* : *coördinate*.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "official"? As far as I'm aware, there's no body legislating on the spelling of the word "coordinate"....

Comment: What's your source?

Comment: "the *official* one"?  Do you have an "authoritative" reference you can cite?  (*The New Yorker*'s in-house style guide doesn't count.)

Comment: Good points for mentioning the trema spelling (new word I learned today -- I just called it an umlaut), but reference to "official" and "correct" is not going to win you many friends here.

Comment: That's an interesting point about "the potential of an uninformed reader to pronounce it "COOR-dinate" with coor rhyming with poor". I have heard a few people pronounce it that way. Some Americans and students of American English.

Comment: Also, the coordinate spelling does look like it would be pronounced as "coo-r-dinate", with coo rhyming with who and moo. Then the r pronounced as an er sound. Put together, the spelling makes it look like it would be pronounced as "coo-er-dinate". That is how it has always seemed to me and still does.